# php and mysql. WHERE date <= X Hours ago?

Tags: php, mysql, date, where-clause

I was wondering what is the best way to write the where statement in PHP where targetDate < Date.Now - HardCodedHours in PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will pull "field1" from table "myTable" where a DATETIME column "targetDate" is older than 12 hours.

```
$hardcodedHours = 12;
$sql = "SELECT field1 FROM myTable WHERE targetDate <= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$hardcodedHours hours")) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: This answer haven't aged well :D

Answer (score 23):

If you mean how to do it in an MySQL query:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE targetDate <= date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$limitTime = time() - $nbHours * 3600;
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE TIMESTAMP(targetDate) < $limitTime;";
```

Or something like that.